# How to reset Xcode snapshots?

Tags: xcode, version-control, xcode5

My Xcode snapshots have gotten completely messed up. I want to tell Xcode to start over with the snapshots for the current project- start taking snapshots as if the project is new. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to start over, delete all of the project's existing snapshots. To delete all the snapshots in a project in Xcode 5, open the Organizer by choosing Window > Organizer. Click the Projects button at the top of the Organizer. Select your project from the left side of the Organizer. The Organizer should show you the location of the project's derived data and snapshots, like the following screenshot:

[image]
Click the Delete button next to the snapshot location to remove all your project's snapshots.